# How to fix a warning on asInstanceOf usage

Tags: scala, static-code-analysis

I'm using scapegoat for Scala static code analysis and I'm getting a warning on a piece of code. Here is the full warning

```
Warning  Use of asInstanceOf  com.sksamuel.scapegoat.inspections.unsafe.AsInstanceOf
asInstanceOf used near cursor.next().asInstanceOf[com.mongodb.casbah.Imports.BasicDBObject]. Consider using pattern matching.
```

The line the warning points to is

```
obj = cursor.next().asInstanceOf[BasicDBObject]
```

Which belongs to this piece of code

```
val q = QueryBuilder.start(fieldName.toString()).is(value)
val cursor = collectionMongo(ARTGROUP_COLLECTION_NAME).find(q.get)
var obj = new BasicDBObject
try {
  while (cursor.hasNext) {
    obj = cursor.next().asInstanceOf[BasicDBObject]
    log.debug(" obj.tostring" + obj.toString())
    retunedList += parseArtGroup(obj)
   }
} catch {
}
```

How can I use pattern matching in the code above?

Comment: What have you tried after having read the pattern matching doc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala stresses type safety a lot, more so than most widespread languages, which is why casting is often seen as a code smell. For the very same reason, the language designer decided to make casting arguably awkward with similarly named `isInstanceOf[T]` and `asInstanceOf[T]` to query a type at runtime and casting it.

To overcome this while still being able to interact with not-so-type-safe libraries, pattern matching is often suggested.

Here is your snippet of code with pattern matching instead of casting:

```
val q = QueryBuilder.start(fieldName.toString()).is(value)
val cursor = collectionMongo(ARTGROUP_COLLECTION_NAME).find(q.get)
var obj = new BasicDBObject
try {
  while (cursor.hasNext) {
    cursor.next() match {                // HERE
      case basicDbObj: BasicDBObject =>  // HERE
        obj = basicDbObj                 // HERE
    }    
    log.debug(" obj.tostring" + obj.toString())
    retunedList += parseArtGroup(obj)
  }
} catch {
}
```

Pattern matching is a Scala feature that allows you to apply something akin to `switch/case` constructs in other languages but with more expressive semantics.

Pattern matching also allows you, among other things, to deconstruct your input in meaningful ways, for example:

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4) match {
  case head :: tail =>
    println(s"The first element is $head and then comes $tail")
}
```

It's worth mentioning that if you don't cover all possible cases you may get a different warning as you may throw a `MatchError` if no matching clause is satisfied.

In case you cannot fully cover all possible cases, you may want to consider the `_` token that symbolizes the wildcard *catch all* pattern as in the following example:

```
cursor.next() match {
  case basicDbObj: BasicDBObject =>
    obj = basicDbObj
  case _ => // default case
    ??? // probably some error handling
}
```

You can read more on pattern matching in Scala [in the official documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html). It's a very well written document and you'll learn a lot about this very powerful feature of Scala.

One nice thing I'd like to add at this point is that Scala's `try/catch` construct uses an analogous syntax.

```
try {
  throw new RuntimeException("kaboom :)")
} catch {
  case e: RuntimeException =>
    println(e.getMessage) // prints "kaboom :)"
}
```

If you are unsure about what you want to catch, Scala ships with a very useful function to destructure non fatal exceptions:

```
import scala.util.control.NonFatal

try {
  throw new RuntimeException("kaboom again!")
} catch {
  case NonFatal(e) =>
    println(e.getMessage) // prints "kaboom again!"
}
```

Quoting [the official documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala/util/control/NonFatal$.html):

> Extractor (*note: more on extractors [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html)*) of non-fatal `Throwables`. Will not match fatal errors like `VirtualMachineError` (for example, `OutOfMemoryError` and `StackOverflowError`, subclasses of `VirtualMachineError`), `ThreadDeath`, `LinkageError`, `InterruptedException`, `ControlThrowable`.

You may want to use something similar to this in your code.

---

On a different note, it looks like in your code you are parsing the objects in an iterator and adding them to a list. It goes beyond your question, but I'd like to offer a small suggestion.

You may want to look into using something like the following to do that:

```
import scala.util.Try

Try(cursor.collect { case o: BasicDBObject => parseArtGroup(o) }).foreach(returnedList ++= _)
```

It may actually be the case that you don't actually need to append your results to `returnedList`, but I'll let you be the judge of that as I don't know your code. If you think this approach makes sense, you can read more on `Try` [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala/util/Try.html) and learn about the `collect` method [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/Iterator.html#collect[B](pf:PartialFunction[A,B]):Iterator[B]).

Comment: Is your first snippet correct? I think logging and appending to list should be inside the while loop.